# How to Insert Data Into Database Table Using jQuery in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

im working on ASP.NET MVC 4 project. well i already insert data into a SQL Server database using jQuery using a post method in .
Now im trying to insert data into 2 tables using the same view, my problem is that i can't passing multiple POST parameters to Web API Controller Method. here is my js function and my controller code, ill apreciate your help

```js
var add_ClientPreste = function () {
    var dataContrat = {
        REFCONTRAT : 'mc1' ,
        DATECREATION  : '2016-05-23',
        DATEFINCONTRAT : '2016-05-23' 
    };       
    var dataClient = {
        C_IDCLIENTGROUPE : 11 ,
        C_IDLOCALITE:332,
        DATECREATION  : '2016-05-23',
        DATEMODIFICATION : '2016-05-23', 
        CODECLIENTPAYEUR : '999999999' ,
        NOMCLIENTPAYEUR : 'morad'
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add_ClientPayeurContrat',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{dataClient},
        success: function (data) { 
            if(data==0) {
                alert("enregistrement avec success : " );
            }
            else {
                alert("error : "+ data );  
            }    
        },
        error : function(data1) {
            alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa " +data1);   
        }
    });
} 
$('#btntest').on('click', function () { 
    add_ClientPreste();
});
$('#btntest').on('click', function () { 
    add_ClientPreste();
});
```

Controller code

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult add_ClientPayeurContrat(SIG_CLIENTPAYEUR dataClient, SIG_CONTRAT dataContrat)
{
    string msg = "";
    try
    {
        ModSigma1.SIG_CLIENTPAYEUR.Add(dataClient);
        ModSigma1.SIG_CONTRAT.Add(dataContrat);
        ModSigma1.SaveChanges();
        msg = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg = ex.Message;
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = msg, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify( { dataContrat:dataContrat, dataClient: dataClient });` and add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: where should i put "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'," ??

Comment: Its an ajax option (just as `dataType: 'json',` is) - just add it anywhere in the `$.ajax({ ..... }); code - the order does not matter

Comment: thank you a lot bro its work (Y) ty again

Comment: stephen, hi again i got one more question( how can i update and delete data in the same project ?). If u can give me some information or some  tutorial ill really apreciate that.

Comment: Why on earth did you accept that answer - it wrong and does not solve you problem - its not even posting `dataContrat `. And if you have another question, then you need to ask a new question :)

Comment: No your wrong i did modify that answer before that i use it, and its work finally, whatever ty for your help

Comment: The answer as given is wrong (you need to use the code in  my comments). Do not accept wrong answers - its misleads other users

Answer (score 0):

```
var add_ClientPreste = function () {

                 var dataContrat = {
                 REFCONTRAT : 'mc1' ,
                 DATECREATION  : '2016-05-23',
                 DATEFINCONTRAT : '2016-05-23' 
                 };

                 var dataClient = {
                 C_IDCLIENTGROUPE : 11 ,
                 C_IDLOCALITE:332,
                 DATECREATION  : '2016-05-23',
                 DATEMODIFICATION : '2016-05-23', 
                 CODECLIENTPAYEUR : '999999999' ,
                 NOMCLIENTPAYEUR : 'morad'
                 };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'add_ClientPayeurContrat',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{dataClient: dataClient},
                    success: function (data) { 
                    if(data==0){
                       alert("enregistrement avec success : " );
                       }
                       else {
                        alert("error : "+ data );  
                        }

                    },
                    error : function(data1){
                        alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa " +data1);   
                    }
                    });
            } 
            $('#btntest').on('click', function () { 
            add_ClientPreste();
            });
           $('#btntest').on('click', function () { 
             add_ClientPreste();
           });
```

//controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult add_ClientPayeurContrat(SIG_CLIENTPAYEUR dataClient, SIG_CONTRAT dataContrat)
    {

        string msg = "";
        try
        {
            ModSigma1.SIG_CLIENTPAYEUR.Add(dataClient);
            ModSigma1.SIG_CONTRAT.Add(dataContrat);
            ModSigma1.SaveChanges();

            msg = "0";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = msg, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

you did not add dataClient: dataClient in ajax.
so please add this.
Hope this will help you.